# Can you disable ASP.NET AJAX for specific browsers

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I am redesigning a web project that requires a lot of involved data entry. I would like to make use of ASP.NET's ajax functionality to improve the user experience. But a large portion of my user base is still using Internet Explorer 7, which has caused problems for us in the past when it comes to AJAX functionality. We cannot request they upgrade, and not supporting them is not an option.

Is there an effective way to disable AJAX functionality for those users on Internet Explorer 7 and provide the full ajax experience for users on more compliant browsers?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what ajax-problems have you met in IE7? We use ajax all the time, and our main userbase is IE7 too, and we have no problems at all (though we don't use ASP.NET).

Comment: Hey Alxandr. Paradoxically, the biggest problem I have had is slowness. Even though AJAX is transfering very little data, the end users still using IE 7 tend to have older computers that execute the javascripts slowly and have a lot of flicker when popping up divs. Also, I have found that a lot of CSS in IE 7 renders "quirky" when it is being drawn by script and not on page load. My end users are unforgiving beasts.

Comment: when you say AJAX are you referring to Update Panels? pure (actual) AJAX shouldn't cause noticeable performance issues

Comment: @BlackTigerX: yes, in this instance I am refering to the update panels and all the dynamic rendering and events. The communication back and forth with the server itself isnt a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), it will accurately detect which browser you have, and set a specific css value in the html tag of the page.  You can then use jquery (or just DOM api) to check the browser version and set a flag that disables your ajax.